# Set time part of DateTime in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

Say I have a datetime object eg `DateTime.now`.  I want to set hours and minutes to 0 (midnight).  How can I do that?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

#### Within a Rails environment:

Thanks to [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb) you can use:

```
DateTime.now.midnight
DateTime.now.beginning_of_day
```

OR

```
DateTime.now.change({ hour: 0, min: 0, sec: 0 })

# More concisely
DateTime.now.change({ hour: 0 })
```

#### Within a purely Ruby environment:

```
now = DateTime.now
DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0, 0, 0, now.zone)
```

OR

```
now = DateTime.now
DateTime.parse(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00%z"))
```

Comment: FWIW, the change method is part of rails not ruby.  The time options (hour, minute, sec) reset cascadingly, so if only the hour is passed, then minute and sec is set to 0. If the hour and minute is passed, then sec is set to 0.

Comment: Be aware that DateTime.now.midnight does not return 24:00:00 as you might expect, it returns 00:00:00 - the same value as beginning_of_day. See my answer as to why this could be important in some scenarios.

Comment: Your first purely ruby solution drops timezone info, your second doesn't

Comment: I've updated the answer to take the timezone into account and replaced the second variation.

@Tony very good catch, they were actually both susceptible to the loss of timezone info at a closer look.

`DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0,0,0, now.zone) != now.to_date.to_datetime`

Comment: TIMEZONE: Can be altered by the keyword offset in the argument hash: DateTime.now.change({ hour: 0, min: 0, sec: 0 offset: '+02:00'})

Comment: Too bad there isn't a `change!()` method. :(

Comment: I am getting error in pure ruby environment : NameError (uninitialized constant DateTime)

Answer (score 38):

Nevermind, got it.  Need to create a new DateTime:

```
DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Good answer. Just wanted to add that those zeros represent HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND and OFFSET (timezone) in that order.

Comment: After failing to get this to work, I learned that with:  

`DateTime.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day, 0, 0, 0)` it works.

Comment: Don't forget: 
```now = DateTime.now```

Comment: Also to note that the last argument needs to be a string of the timezone e.g.("-0700") for MST, not an integer

Comment: Unless you're dealing with historical dates, DON'T USE `DateTime`.

You'll get annoying issues if you live in a country that has daylight saving time like the UK.

See an explanation here. https://gist.github.com/pixeltrix/e2298822dd89d854444b

Comment: @Ekkstein I advise obtaining the current time once (`now = Time.now`) rather than three separate times, on the remote but possible chance one of the values changes during evaluation, at the boundaries between months and years. I.e., what if the day has changed between the evaluation of `Time.now.day` and `Time.now.month`?

Answer (score 6):

**Warning**: `DateTime.now.midnight` and `DateTime.now.beginning_of_day` return the same value (which is the zero hour of the current day - midnight does not return 24:00:00 as you would expect from its name).

So I am adding this as further info for anyone who might use the accepted answer to calculate midnight x days in the future.

For example, a 14 day free trial that should expire at midnight on the 14th day:

```
DateTime.now.midnight + 14.days
```

is the morning of the 14th day, which equates to a 13.x day trial (x is the part of the day left over - if now is noon, then it's 13.5 day trial).

You would actually need to do this:

```
DateTime.now.midnight + 15.days
```

to get midnight on the 14th day.

For this reason I always prefer to use `beginning_of_day`, since that is 00:00:00.  Using midnight can be misleading/misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

If you use it often consider install this gem to improve date parse:

https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

```
require 'chronic'

Chronic.parse('this 0:00')
```

Comment: I am not sure why this answer is marked as right. It doesn't really answer the question. I know how to parse a string to a date. But I would like to know how to change a particular part of a given date instance. For example the year. Any ideas? In Java I would just use the setter for year. But it doesn't work in Ruby :-(

Comment: I don't trust chronic gem anymore. It's really outdated. I had problem in parsing date-time at run-time in my app which resulted in loss of business.